# How to pass string value of MVC DropDownList as a parameter to method in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CourseField", new SelectList(SmartJob.Web.UI.Helper.ProfessionalCourseDropDownHelper.CourseCategoriesDropDown, "Key", "Value", 0), "Field of Study")
```

I want to pass the selected record as a parameter to a method in my contoller. How can I pass that value?

This is the method in my controller.

```
public PartialViewResult SearchCourseCriteria(string CourseField){

}
```

Comment: Show your controller method

Comment: I modified the question. and HTTPmethod is Get.

Comment: Then it need `Html.BeginForm("SearchCourseCriteria", yourControllerName, FormMethod.Get)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use form post like this:

```
<form method="get" action="/YourController/SearchCourseCriteria">
    @Html.DropDownList("CourseField", new SelectList(SmartJob.Web.UI.Helper.ProfessionalCourseDropDownHelper.CourseCategoriesDropDown, "Key", "Value", 0), "Field of Study")
<button>Submit<button />
<form />
```

Then your controller will be like this:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchCourseCriteria(string CourseField)
{
...//Controller logic here
}
```

Depending on your `value` type in DropDown it could be not `string`, but `int` or anythig else...

Comment: I did it in that way. Im using HTTPmethod = GET. This isn't working.

Comment: @SumuduDeZoysa have you add `method="get"` attribute to `form`?

Comment: Yes I added. I passing another value from the text field. It is working perfectly. But I cant pass the value from dropDownList to method as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @teo van kot It is working. I did some foolish thing there. Thanks a lot for ur kind help. :)